# How to obtain List properties via REST API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, marketingcloudapi

For example, if I have a List ID of 53, can I use that to obtain the properties of the List via REST API? Properties would include name, number of subscribers, external key, created date, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Have you looked here? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/routes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list details in this REST endpoint:

```
GET /email/v1/lists/{{listID}}
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Returns:

```
{
    "listId": 12345678,
    "customerKey": "All Subscribers",
    "name": "All Subscribers",
    "description": "Contains all subscribers",
    "categoryId": 1234,
    "createdDate": "20xx-06-28T09:39:49.64",
    "lastModifiedDate": "20xx-06-28T09:39:49.64",
    "lastModifiedByName": "xxxxxxx",
    "sourceListId": 0,
    "sourceListName": "",
    "lastRefreshedDate": "20xx-06-28T09:39:49.64",
    "subConfirm": false,
    "confirmLandingPage": "",
    "isConfirmLandingPage": false,
    "useDefaultLandingPage": true,
    "isPublic": false,
    "listObjectId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

You can then use this endpoint to get the subscriber level counts of the list:

```
GET /email/v1/lists/{{listid}}/subscriberstatuscounts
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Returns:

```
{
    "bounceCount": 10102,
    "heldCount": 569,
    "unsubscribedCount": 30321,
    "activeCount": 500548
}
```

You can then add those all up and get the total list size.

Or you can use this Endpoint to get just that specific overall number:

```
GET /email/v1/lists/subscribercount/{{listid}}
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Returns:

```
{
    "listId": 12345678,
    "subscriberCount": 501345352
}
```

Comment: Hey @Gortonington. For reference, was this documented anywhere? I wasn't able to find any documentation on the GET /email/v1/lists/{{listID}} endpoint.

Comment: good call out, no I think this is one of the undocumented endpoints so all the normal considerations around an undocumented endpoint apply