# Get all subscriber lists via Marketing Cloud APIs

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

Hoping you Marketing Cloud pros might have some thoughts here.

I am investigating the feasibility of having a custom related list in SF that shows all the lists a contact is on. I followed [this reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/retrieving_all_lists_a_subscriber_is_on.html) but it only returns the List Ids not the names etc. None of the info I am looking for appears to be on that object.

I also found [this post and what seems like a totally undocumented end point](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357438/how-to-obtain-list-properties-via-rest-api).

It gives the list info but for one list at a time. Is there any way to just fetch all a subscribers list details in one API call ?

Comment: If you use SQL query with `_ListSubscribers ` data view, you can get the ListName attribute there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the `_ListSubscribers` data view, you can retrieve 2 times on `ListSubscriber` (to get the list ID) and `List`(to get the list name)

Here is the sample code

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");

var listID = [];
var listName = [];

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

// Get all List ID
var cols = ["SubscriberKey", "ListID", "Status"];
var filter = {Property: "SubscriberKey", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: "YOUR SUBKEY HERE"};
var data = prox.retrieve("ListSubscriber", cols, filter);

if (data.Results.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Results; i++) {
        listID.push(data.Results[i].ListID);
    }
}

// Get all List Name
var cols = ["ListName"];

if (listID.length > 1) {
    var filter = {Property: "ID", SimpleOperator: "IN", Value: listID};
} else {
    var filter = {Property: "ID", SimpleOperator: "equals", Value: listID[0]};
}
var data = prox.retrieve("List", cols, filter);

if (data.Results.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Results; i++) {
        listName.push(data.Results[i].ListName);
    }
}

// Print your list Name
Write(Stringify(listName));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I am learning MC now. I assume that what we need if I want to start with a Salesforce Contact ID and get all the lists that contact is part of is a custom endpoint using AmpScript or SSJS ?

Comment: @BrooksJohnson If it relates to performing an API call, I would choose SSJS. The way I showed above using retrieve method via the WSProxy library (for SOAP objects). IMHO, if it doesn't require to call API, you can use SQL query with `_ListSubscribers` data view, much easier

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use the SOAP API to achieve what you're looking to do. It takes to separate operations. There is not a single request that would give you all the data you need for your solution. Firstly, you can get metadata about your lists (IDs and ListNames) by doing a Retrieve on the [List](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/list.html) object:

**Sample Request**

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
     <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
       </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>List</ObjectType>
                <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Properties>ListName</Properties>
                <Properties>ID</Properties>
                <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
                <Properties>Description</Properties>
                <Properties>Category</Properties>
                <Properties>Type</Properties>
                <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
                <Properties>ListClassification</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Sample Response**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:4f2b8e28-e8eb-4c2d-aea0-b72ebf55114e</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9d2ddea0-89ab-433f-9edc-7398edf0e3f2</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-486f855b-2089-4ae2-9a4a-ccb3a579c802">
                <wsu:Created>2022-11-02T03:17:51Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-11-02T03:22:51Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>a1155b9d-1f8c-41bd-b574-e0f75f228cc5</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="List">
                <Client>
                    <ID>12345</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ID>8661</ID>
                <ObjectID>ae2cc987-39cf-41c7-9a25-f40ad6682ea7</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>List1</CustomerKey>
                <ListName>Some List</ListName>
                <Category>508</Category>
                <Type>Private</Type>
                <Description />
                <ListClassification>ExactTargetList</ListClassification>
            </Results>
            <Results xsi:type="List">
                <Client>
                    <ID>12345</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ID>8675</ID>
                <ObjectID>5a80d785-dd75-41a4-a9f1-5e9db09e122b</ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>List2</CustomerKey>
                <ListName>Some Other List</ListName>
                <Category>508</Category>
                <Type>Private</Type>
                <Description />
                <ListClassification>ExactTargetList</ListClassification>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Then you would need to do a Retrieve on the [ListSubscriber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/listsubscriber.html) object to retrieve the IDs and statuses of all the lists the contact is part of:

**Sample Request**

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
       <fueloauth>{{_token}}</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
                <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>
                <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
                <Properties>ListID</Properties>
                <Properties>Status</Properties>
                <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>MyEighteenCharacterContactId</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Sample Response**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:1c91a23f-fbe2-49d4-bf07-0ecc3d0cc694</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:24f75e51-eefd-4046-b2ba-cdf555fe4555</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-d0352614-69fa-481e-a987-6a1bd5e4e1b9">
                <wsu:Created>2022-11-02T03:37:28Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2022-11-02T03:42:28Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>c9c0c2b0-0a00-4d1e-a6e5-fa1d6ea8a428</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="ListSubscriber">
                <Client>
                    <ID>12345</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <ListID>8661</ListID>
                <SubscriberKey>MyEighteenCharacterContactId</SubscriberKey>
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```